# Is there a method like "before_request" in multiple-threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask

There is a method called @before_request in flask,

Is there a method like this in multiple-threads?

what I want to do:

```py
import threading
threading.current_thread().__dict__['id'] = 'id001'

def say_id():
    # how to change this step by a method like before_request
    threading.current_thread().__dict__['id'] =threading.main_thread().__dict__.get('id', '') 
    # so I can use this main thread id simple with one line 
    print(threading.current_thread().__dict__.get('id'))


t1 = threading.Thread(target=say_id)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=say_id)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

To be clear:The point is how to make sub-thread inherit sth from main thread

Comment: If you want child thread to get some additional parameters on start, you need just to inherit from `threading.Thread` and add additional params to `__init__` constructor.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev It's possible to do that before every new thread start? I would like to do this with a global setting

Comment: `__init__` exactly takes place before thread start, thread starts only after you do `thread_object.start()`

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev would you mind to describe this in detial, I know __init__ method will work perfectly, but how to make this globally without do a extra inherit thread class to get this

Comment: The problem with `before_request` is that it is defined inside `Scaffold` class, then `Flask` class inherits from ` Scaffold` class, so if you want similar functionality for `threading.Thread`, you have to inherit from `Thread` class and create `before_start` there. There is no any other magic. Other choices 1. inherit from `Thread` and change `__init__` 2. create class decorator and then inherit from `Thread` 3. use `Thread` target function with additional parameters.

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev got the idea now, thanks a lot